# Import pipe delimited txt file into spark dataframe in databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, txt

I have a data file saved as .txt format which has a header row at the top, and is pipe delimited. I am working in databricks, and am needing to create a spark dataframe of this data, with all columns read in as StringType(), the headers defined by the first row, and the columns separated based on the pipe delimiter.

When importing .csv files I am able to set the delimiter and header options. However, I am not able to get the .txt files to import in the same way.

Example Data (completely made up)... for ease, please imagine it is just called datafile.txt:

URN|Name|Supported

12233345757777701|Tori|Yes

32313185648456414|Dave|No

46852554443544854|Steph|No

I would really appreciate a hand in getting this imported into a Spark dataframe so that I can crack on with other parts of the analysis. Thank you!

Comment: "_I am not able to get the `.txt` files to import in the same way._" - Can you explain? Do you get any errors? `.txt` is just a file extension but the format is CSV so you can read it with `spark.read.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any delimiter separated file is a good candidate for csv reading methods.  The 'c' of csv is mostly by convention.  Thus nothing stops us from reading this:

```
col1|col2|col3
0|1|2
1|3|8
```

Like this (in pure python):

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path
with Path("pipefile.txt").open() as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter="|")
    data = list(reader)
print(data)
```

Since whatever custom reader your libraries are using probably uses `csv.reader` under the hood you simply need to figure out how to pass the right separator to it.

@blackbishop notes in a comment that

```py
spark.read.csv("datafile.text", header=True, sep="|")
```

would be the appropriate spark call.

Comment: No! Spark has its own data source readers so please don't confuse the OP using pure Python, that's not what they are asking for.

Comment: @blackbishop if you post a spark answer I'll happily delete this one :)  But the basic point--that the 'c' in csv is irrelevant---stands.

Comment: I'm not posting an answer as the question is not clear enough for me. Reading those text files should be simple as `spark.read.csv("datafile.text", header=True, sep="|")` but I think the problem is something else so waiting for OP's clarifications.

Comment: I read it as simply not knowing that any delimiter separated file is a good candidate for csv reading; that was all I was trying to show.  I'll edit the answer to make that clear. **EDIT** edited, but I'll still happily delete this answer if a. the real problem is different or b. you post the spark solution yourself.

Comment: @blackbishop Apologies, you are absolutely right that was exactly the solution. I must have been missing something when I tried it yesterday. Thank you very much for solving my issue so straightforwardly.

Comment: I have accepted the answer above as it explained the issue I was misunderstanding; that they are essentially the same under the hood, and with your amendment on there it solved my issue. Thank you both.